# Javascript not loading after render partial via ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I'm having troubles with the javascript of a partial that I'm rendering via ajax.

The partial has an HTML table, in this file I have javascript functions to manage the interactions with the table.

In another file, I'm rendering this partial via ajax, like this:

```
   $.ajax(
    type: 'GET'
    url: "#{get_debts_by_guardian_services_students_path}"
    data: person_id: person_id)
```

The method I'm calling via ajax returns some variables that the table needs to render.

But when the partial renders none of the javascript functions are working, I'm guessing is because the ajax call, but don't know how to solve this.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: is your ajax call wrapped inside a $(document).ready(function() {}) ?

Comment: Can you post the response that you're getting after the ajax call?
If it is in string format and in case you're handling it in JSON format you will need to parse the response.

Comment: @GabrielMesquita yes, i have $(document).ready -> then the ajax call

Comment: Ok so as @Harman said, post the response for the ajax call so we can take a look

Comment: @Harman can you explain that more?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zGjed8q8 @GabrielMesquita here's the response

Comment: have you tried to use append instead of html? With the htmlToRender?

Comment: Yes, didn't work @GabrielMesquita